# CV2.rectangle expects integer on windows but works with float on Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, opencv

I was working on some code on ubuntu and tried to run it on windows.

I get this error on Windows: `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`

```
self.rect1 = [(self.width / 2) - 10, (self.height / 2) - 10]
self.rect2 = [(self.width / 2) + 10, (self.height / 2) + 10]
cv2.rectangle(self.image, tuple(self.rect1), tuple(self.rect2), (255,0,0), -1)
```

I understand I can solve this by using `int()` but I would like to use the floating values as I did on Ubuntu.

Is there a reason this is OS specific?

**Update**

I believe the @mesutpiskin's answer is correct. If I define the variables as float manually:

```
self.rect1 = [200.5, 200.5]
self.rect2 = [210.5, 210.5]
```

I get the same error on Ubuntu. I guess Ubuntu returns int during the division instead of float. Printing the type confirms this.

```
rect3 = [(width / 2) - 10, (height / 2) - 10]   
rect4 = [(width / 2) + 10, (height / 2) + 10]
print(type(rect3[0]))
```

Outputs: `<type 'int'>`

Comment: The CVPoint object only receives variables of type int. Could it be that Ubuntu is doing the type conversion itself? Finally, are the versions the same? CvPoint Ref: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dd1/structCvPoint.html

Comment: Are you using Python 2 on Ubuntu (which does int division) and Python 3 on Windows (which does float division) perhaps?

Comment: @w-m I used python 2 on both Ubuntu and windows.